# Problem with VIM - "f" calling the "fold" command instead of "find"

Tags: python, vim

This is happening in python files.

For example, I want to do type "fC" in normal mode, and instead of finding the first "C" character, it is just doing code fold toggling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real answer:

Are you using [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1494)? Under 4, it says that pressing "f" toggles the fold (in certain conditions).

Original answer:

I'm not sure what fC does, because it doesn't do anything in my version of vim, but normally to use find "C," you can use "/C" followed by enter.

Comment: You're talking about searching within a document. "fC" moves the cursor forward to the first instance of char "C" (e.g. "f:" moves to the next ":").

Comment: Oh, I see, fC moves the cursor to the first instance of C on the line.

Comment: Are you using this plugin?  Under 4, it says that pressing "f" toggles the fold (in certain conditions).

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1494

Comment: Yes, that script did it, it had a map to the 'f' key. I remapped it to <leader>f and everything is groovy now!